# using if statements for list

Tags: list, python-3.x

How do I tell my program to do a certain actions according to what is givin in a string?

For example if there are strings in the list:

```
li = ["Hello", "Day"]
```

you do a particular action.

if there are integers in the list:

```
li = [1,2,3,4,3232]
```

you do someother action

if there are booleans

```
li=[False]
```

do some other action.

I want to check the object type of a list.

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific. Are you checking if one list exactly matches another? Or for the types in the list?

Comment: Where is the question exactly? You want to understand how to check an object type?

Comment: You want to vary behaviour by the type of the list contents?

Comment: If you are sure that all the elements in the list have the same type, then you can simply have multiple if depending on the value of type(li[0])

Comment: yes I want to check the object type

Comment: Can the items in the lists be different types, or will they always be all of the same type?

Comment: They can be of different types

Answer (score 1):

You can use either

```
if isinstance(li[0], str):
    ...
elif isinstance(li[0], int):
    ...
elif isinstance(li[0], bool):
    ...
```

or you can create separate functions and a dispatch dictionary:

```
def function_for_str(li):
    ... process a list of strings ...

def function_for_int(li):
    ... process a list of ints ...

def function_for_bool(li):
    ... process a list of booleans ...

funcs = {str: function_for_str,
         int: function_for_int,
         bool: function_for_bool}
```

and then use `type`:

```
funcs[type(li[0])](li)  # Will call the specific function
```

Note however that in Python each element of a list can have a different type, and you can also face an empty list (a list with no elements at all).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement the following code.

```
for item in my_list:
    if isinstance(item, int):
        do_int_related_stuff(item)
    elif isinstance(item, str):
        do_str_related_stuff(item)
    elif isinstance(item, bool):
        do_bool_related_stuff(item)
    else:
        do_generic_stuff(item)
```

If you wan to check if all items in a list is of one particular type, you can do something like this.

```
if all([isinstance(item, str) for item in my_list]):
    do_str_related_stuff(my_list)
```

Note however that the latter one is true if you are dealing with an empty list.

```
>>> all(isinstance(item, bool) for item in [])
True
```